# how can you populate a substitution variable with the value returned by select max(colx) from tabley in sqlplus script?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, substitution

I want to put the value returned by `select max(column) from mytable` so that I might use that value in several subsequent SQL statements in the same script that is run using SQL*PLUS rather than executing the `select max(column) from mytable` in the numerous instances within the subsequent SQL within the script. There are several ways to accomplish this but being able to define a substitution variable and then set its value with a select statement certainly seems the simplest and most clear way to write this since bind variables seem to demand a different style of writing, higher level of complexity, and less clear for those who might need to make changes in the future.

Answer (score 1):

No problem - use a **variable**. Here's how:

Declare a variable; use `exec` to put a value into it:

```
SQL> var max_deptno number;
SQL> exec select max(deptno) into :max_deptno from emp;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

What does it contain?

```
SQL> print max_deptno

MAX_DEPTNO
----------
        30
```

Use it in those *subsequent selects* you have:

```
SQL> select ename, job, sal from emp where deptno = :max_deptno;

ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- --------- ----------
ALLEN      SALESMAN        1600
WARD       SALESMAN        1250
MARTIN     SALESMAN        1250
BLAKE      MANAGER         2850
TURNER     SALESMAN        1500
JAMES      CLERK            950

6 rows selected.

SQL> select * from dept where deptno = :max_deptno;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        30 SALES          CHICAGO

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for info. Yes, this did work well to get value into the Bind Variable but by itself did not solve all the related problems. Trying to use the bind variable in "create table mytable as select * from inp_table where  columnx = :max_columnx" failed yielding "ORA-01027: bind variables not allowed for data definition operations" .  To solve this in the easiest manner I inserted the following line after loading the Bind Variable value:   "define mymax =  :max_columnx".  Using the Substitution Variable generated no errors.

Comment: Spoke too soon. Apparently bind variables can not be used in "CREATE TABLE" as select (DDL) and when I executed "define var = bind_var the substitution simply substitutes back the bind var so I get the ORA- 01027 error anyway. I could just write the CREATE Table to use "WHERE Colx = (select max(colx) from table)" but the whole intent was to replace the select execution with essentially a constant literal previously determined and stored to minimize resource utilization.

Comment: Exactly, bind variables can't be used in CREATE TABLE, that's nothing now nor unusual. A workaround - if it is a .SQL script that contains many references to the same value - would be to use some kind of a *placeholder*, e.g. `... where colx = PAR_MAXX` and you'd perform *replace all* in your editor, replacing PAR_MAXX with (for example) 6637 (or whichever value it is). Or, switch to dynamic SQL, but that doesn't scale and is difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> var max_loaD_MONTH VARCHAR(20);
SQL> exec select max(LOAD_MONTH) into :max_LOAD_MONTH from CASETABLE;)

SQL> CREATE TABLE NEW_CASES AS SELECT * FROM CASETABLE WHERE ROWNUM < 1;

SQL> INSERT INTO NEW_CASES AS SELECT * FROM CASETABLE WHERE LOAD_MONTH = :max_load_month;
```

This allows me to create a table containing only the most recent month's case entries and to put all other case entries into another temp table (`where load_month != :max_load_month`). I needed to do this because the update of the case table was running over 20 hours and by putting only those records being updated in a temporary table the update only takes 5 minutes, then I can recreate the `casetable` using a UNION ALL between the two temporary tables. I think this will work but did not want to have to use the `select max(load_month)` twice in the update query - seemed too much to get a value in the format of 2019-11 for every record processed.

Thanks for the help. I am still thinking that a method to assign the value of the `select
max(load_month)` (i.e. 2019-11) to a substitution variable would have been ideal. In SQL Developer `define max_load_month = (select max(load_month) from casetable)` worked, but not as I was hoping it would. It appeared that in SQLDeveloper it substituted the query and then the query was executed where the variable was used, when I had intended to assign the value of the query to `max_load_month` rather than the query. However in PL/SQL the define failed because the query was malformed.

Comment: I suggest you become familiar with [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). I think it will make your posts easier to read and understand.